# Is it possible to use kineticjs with native canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kineticjs

I'm creating an animated diagram and I'm trying to use a native canvas element as well as kineticjs for the animations.  I know that kinetic creates a hidden canvas element, but my question is.  Is it possible to stop kinetic from doing this and implement the kinetic framework into a native canvas element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every KineticJS layer is a visible drawing canvas plus an invisible canvas used for Kinetic's internal purposes.

The drawing canvas is a "native canvas element".

Normally Kinetic does all the drawing for you, but...

**You can use Kinetic.Shape objects to issue native drawing commands directly to the html canvas element**.

The Kinetic.Shape object gives you a canvas context that you can use to create your custom diagram.

This context is actually a Kinetic wrapper around the actual context.  If there is a command that the wrapper hasn't implemented yet you can get the real canvas context like this:

```
var myRealCanvasContext=this.getContext()._context;
```